# Compare two timeframes in two tables to receive validated timeframes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables containing the same fields:

- "*(first/second)id*", identifying the row
- "*valid_from*", identifying the beginning date - involved in the join
- "*valid_until*", identifying the ending date - involved in the join
- "*attribute*", the matching information

Table "*first*":

| firstID | valid_from | valid_until | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 932 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-20 | hello |
| 932 | 2021-01-21 | 2021-10-07 | whats |
| 932 | 2021-10-08 | 9999-12-31 | up |

Table "*second*":

| secondID | valid_from | valid_until | sk_firstID | attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1269 | 2021-01-21 | 2021-10-03 | 932 | I |
| 1269 | 2021-10-04 | 2021-10-07 | 932 | need |
| 1269 | 2021-10-08 | 9999-12-31 | 932 | your |
| 1123 | 2021-12-02 | 9999-12-31 | 932 | help |

Now I have to build timeframes to compare both tables and get all combinations, where the data matches.

Given the sample input tables, expected output should look like this:

| first ID | secondID | valid_from | attribute1 | attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 932 |  | 2021-01-04 | hello |  |
| 932 | 1269 | 2021-01-21 | whats | I |
| 932 | 1269 | 2021-10-04 | whats | need |
| 932 | 1269 | 2021-10-08 | up | your |
| 932 | 1123 | 2021-12-02 | up | help |

There are challenges I'm facing and didn't get to solve right now:

1. If there is no corresponding timeframe-match it should show null in the corresponding row
2. It can happen both ways that there are two or more timeframes that can fall into the timeframe of the other table and vice versa.
3. It occurs, that different ID's appear in table two, related to one firstID

I already tried to join the two tables with some conditions but never got the result I needed.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT f.firstid,
       s.secondid,
       attribute,
       attribute2,
       CASE WHEN f.valid_from >= s.valid_from 
            THEN cast(f.valid_from as date)
            ELSE cast(s.valid_from as date)
       END AS valid_from
FROM first f
LEFT JOIN second AS s ON f.firstid = s.sk_firstID
                     AND s.valid_from <= f.valid_until
```

Here's my current output:
[image]

Here's the DDL to generate and populate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE first
    ([firstID] int, [valid_from] datetime, [valid_until] datetime, [attribute] varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO first
    ([firstID], [valid_from], [valid_until], [attribute])
VALUES
    (932, '2021-01-04 00:00:00', '2021-01-20 00:00:00', 'hello'),
    (932, '2021-01-21 00:00:00', '2021-10-07 00:00:00', 'whats'),
    (932, '2021-10-08 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00', 'up')
;

CREATE TABLE second
    ([secondID] int, [valid_from] datetime, [valid_until] datetime, [sk_firstID] int, [attribute2] varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO second
    ([secondID], [valid_from], [valid_until], [sk_firstID], [attribute2])
VALUES
    (1269, '2021-01-21 00:00:00', '2021-10-03 00:00:00', 932, 'I'),
    (1269, '2021-10-04 00:00:00', '2021-10-07 00:00:00', 932, 'need'),
    (1269, '2021-10-08 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00', 932, 'your'),
    (1123, '2021-12-02 00:00:00', '9999-12-31 00:00:00', 932, 'help')
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose both dates from the table "*second*" inside dates from the table "*first*" and you should get your output:

```
SELECT f.firstid,
       s.secondid,
       attribute,
       attribute2,
       CASE WHEN f.valid_from >= COALESCE(s.valid_from, -1) 
            THEN CAST(f.valid_from AS DATE)
            ELSE CAST(s.valid_from AS DATE)
       END AS valid_from
FROM      first  f
LEFT JOIN second s 
       ON f.firstid = s.sk_firstID
      AND s.valid_from >= f.valid_from
      AND s.valid_until <= f.valid_until
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3395299b9819c99aa3b85fb33a363717).

**Note**: in case your output should get you way more rows than the ones given here, one option is to do a cartesian product and filter out the rows you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate. I had to slightly modify it for other cases that occur but it definitly went in the right direction!